# Not cycling throigh words in string tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i have this code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from random import seed, choice
from string import ascii_letters

seed(42)

text = """
this is a test
"""

def do_stuff():
    for word in text.split():
        s = ''.join(word)
    color = "black"
    l.config(text=s, fg=color)
    root.after(240, do_stuff)

root = tk.Tk()

l = tk.Label(text='', font=("Helvetica", 60))
l.pack(expand=True)

do_stuff()
root.mainloop()
```

when ran, this code:

```py
for word in text.split():
   s = ''.join(word)
```

should make all of the words in the string appear at intervals of 240ms, but when ran, the screen only says the last word in the the string "test", and doesn't cycle through them at 240ms per word. does anyone know why.

i have a feeling i need to restructure the for loop, as i furgure it is looping through all of the words before showing them. but i dont know how to go about this

Comment: What if you try making your timer longer than 240ms? `text` splits to 4 words, so they would take less than 1s to display all 4. Could it have already looped through all 4 by the time the root window gets spawned?

Comment: @AdamSmooch i tried and that doesnt seem to help unfortunately

Comment: Have you ever tried to think about what will be the result of `s` after the for loop? Why do you think that the for loop *"should make all the words in the string appear at intervals of 240ms"*?